# Create MPEG DASH segments from h264 files

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, h.264, mpeg-dash

Basically I have a bunch of h264 files from a camera feed....

So there is no audio.  What I would like to do is make DASH segments out of these h264 files and do live streaming to a Media Source (like in Chrome).  I don't want to first concatenate the h264 into a giant h264 then copy it into a mp4 container and lastly make DASH manifests.  Instead would love to find a way to turn the h264 directly into DASH segments (mpd files).

Ideas?

Comment: Read the MediaSource spec.  Need an init segment with a moov box then subsequent media segments with moof plus multiple mdat boxes.  In other words, movie metadata plus the tracks.  Seems really similar to the mp4 setup.  Init segment is a mp4 with the mdat stuff. Media segments are mp4 with the moov box.

Comment: Finally getting my head around the feeds to the Media Source buffer.  Apparently the buffer deals with stringing together streams of initial+media segments.  Google's demo page (http://dash-mse-test.appspot.com/dash-player.html) has a bunch of representations (initial+media but feed by range rather than separate URLs).  See that I have to have moof fragments and thus the suggestion of using mp4fragment.  Got it.

What would probably suit me best is a single moov like you say that gets generated.  Then each media segment request needs the h264 wrapped in a fragmented mp4.

Comment: Can you post an a example MPD file showing how you created the  segments?

Comment: @Tommy, Absolutely.  Have been putting off publishing something on GitHub for a while (lack of time).  But will push back a comment here when something is available.  Hardest part for me was parsing in Nodejs.  What is your programming language/platform?

Comment: nodejs, i can possibly help if you publish working examples on github. check out the xmljs node package. it should help.

Comment: @Tommy, Check.  Will try to get on it over the weekend.